# How to change locale parameter of SwiftMoment?

Tags: swift, swift3

I imported [SwiftMoment](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftMoment) from Cocoapods, and I display the date from now like that:

```
cell.dateText!.text = moment(notification.createdAt!).fromNow()
```

The result is in english: **5 hours ago**

I would change the **locale parameter** to display it in french, but I can't find how to do it in Swift. I jumped to `moment()` definition to find how it is handled, but I can't figure it out.

---

### What I tried:

The definition is:

```
public func moment(_ date: Date,
                   timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.current,
                   locale: Locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent) -> Moment {
    return Moment(date: date, timeZone: timeZone, locale: locale)
}
```

I tried to init moment with those three parameters, but I get this error:

> Argument labels '(_:, _:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Does anyone know something about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name the 2nd and 3rd parameter to this function. Try

```
let frLocale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
let str = moment(notification.createdAt!, locale: frLocale).fromNow()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have `6 hours ago` written.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's a bug in `SwiftMoment`. It uses `"%1.0f seconds ago"` as the localized formatting string, but the Strings file in fr.lproj only has a localization for the string `"%d seconds ago"`